# How to avoid database connection, while debugging

Tags: python-3.x, debugging

I am wondering what the most pythonic way is to avoid making connections to databases while being in debugging/development. Since I moved my project away from the server (where the db is settled) to my local machine, this option would become quite comfortable.

I guess I could use the mock module for that in a very uncommon approach since it is not a test case...

those are the lines which are of my interest to be

```
with apputils.create_cx_oracle_connection() as connection:
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
```

`apputils.create_cx_oracle_connection()` returns an cx_Oracle connection.

I can not work around those lines since they are being used in a important decorator which wraps the function which are doing the important business logic in a later process.

This line is easy for me to been altered if the cli flag --no-db is set, since I can change the return object of my module.

```
with apputils.create_cx_oracle_connection() as connection:
```

But it will throw an error at this point since this method will not be available...

```
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
```

At this point I could either use an faked object with a cursor method, which will be returned from `create_cx_oracle_connection`, when --no-db was used as cli option or do some error handling, but maybe there is something more pythonic for that I am not aware of

Comment: The doc https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/tracing_sql.html shows how to overload the connection routines if you decide you don't actually want to create a DB connection - it sounds like you know this?  However, that would mean anything in the code that needs a connection isn't going to work.  Why not install the Oracle XE free database on your machine, or create a free Oracle Cloud account (https://www.oracle.com/cloud/free)

Comment: Thx. I actually don't wanted to overload the Connection class. It would be work fine though if I would run the tests with a test flag which leads to using my custom Connection Subclass instead the origin. But I hoped for a better solution than that

Comment: If more people working on the project each of them needs to install Oracle XE free on their local machine. I want to ease the workflow by avoiding such workarounds

Comment: Install one DB and share it?  Create an Oracle Cloud account (even an 'Always Free' one) and use a DB there? https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/appdev/python/quickstartpython.html

Answer (score 0):

You can mock out the call to connect with your own object. Adding `__enter__` and `__exit__` methods to the object will allow it to work as a context manager. This would then need a cursor method which returns a cursor object where you can define the methods that you would like to test.

```
class MockCursor:
    # Add the cursor methods you want to test

class MockConnect:
    def __enter__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self

    def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
        pass

    @staticmethod
    def cursor():
        return MockCursor()

@mock.patch.object(apputils, "create_cx_oracle_connection")
def test_foo(mock_connect):
    mock_connect.return_value = MockConnect()
```

I have added a more complete example on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52433011/how-to-mock-cx-oracle-cursor-in-python)